# Can trigger.io open a TCP socket?

Tags: sockets, tcp, trigger.io

Is there an easy way to open a TCP socket to connect a TCP server? Should I use socketjs, jsocket or something else?

I try to develop a cross-platform application to connect to a TCP server and pull data from it.

Thanks

Comment: I am going to say "no" as of v1.3.  Although I never tried using the request module - http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/request.html - with a different port or tcp://

Answer (score 1):

No, we do not have an API for that at present. But you can use WebSockets on iOS, and libraries like socket.io which fall back to long-polling on Android.

If you email us at support@trigger.io we can advise on your specific requirements and see if it could make sense to offer a native API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [trigger.io-tcp](https://github.com/vintasoftware/trigger.io-tcp), an android-only trigger.io native module that allows you to open TCP sockets for sending/receiving data.

You can use it if you need sockets only for Android or fork it and write the iOS part.